# How to input an array of random values into a binary search tree algirithm

Tags: javascript, arrays, input, output, binary-search-tree

I have an array with randomly generated numbers and I have to input them into a binary search tree algorithm, then to output them and visually represent it.
Here is the code :

```
//buttons and input
range:<input type="text"  id="input1">
lenght:<input type="text"  id="input2">
<input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="javascript:myJsFunction()">
<script>
//random number generator
function myJsFunction(){
    var x=document.getElementById('input1').value;
    var n=document.getElementById('input2').value;
    var data=[];

    for (var i = 0; i < n ; i++){
        data[i]=Math.floor(Math.random()*x);
    }
}


//binary search tree algorithm
class Node {
    constructor(data, left = null, right = null) {
        this.data = data;
        this.left = left;
        this.right = right;
     }
}

class BinaryTree {
    constructor() {
        this.root = null;
    }

    add(data) {
        const node = this.root;
        if (node === null) {
            this.root = new Node(data);
            return;
        } else {
            const searchTree = function(node) {
                if (data < node.data) {
                    if (node.left === null) {
                        node.left = new Node(data);
                        return;
                    } else if (node.left !== null) {
                        return searchTree(node.left);
                    }
                } else if (data > node.data) {
                    if (node.right === null) {
                        node.right = new Node(data);
                        return;
                    } else if (node.right !== null) {
                        return searchTree(node.right);
                    }
                } else {
                     return null;
                }
            };

            return searchTree(node);
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

I need a simple visual representation, something like sticks from the root and nodes (left-right). I couldn't find anything on array to binary tree or proper visualization so i would require some help.

Comment: Please fix the indenting. That makes is easier to read!
And there is no need to thank us in your question.

Comment: uh, I feel like you might have way too much code here. In your constructor, I think all you need is `(data)` and then `this.data = data;` and below that `this.children = [];`. I mean it seems that the concept of children is missing from your tree. I believe you need to initialize an empty array for storing children and assign it the children property like I just showed you in this comment.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the concept of children is missing from your tree. I believe you need to initialize an empty array for storing children and assign it the children property.

```
class Node {
    constructor(data){
        this.data = data;
        this.children = [];
    }

    add(data) {
        this.children.push(new Node(data));
    }

    remove(data) {
        this.children = this.children.filter(node => {
            return node.data !== data;
        });
    }

}

class Tree {
  this.root = null;
}
```

So I created a new node inside the add method with data. Then take a newly created node and push it to the current nodes children array.

So we initialized our data variable , created an empty array of children  so every single node has this children array so every child can have some number of children.

The add and remove method belong to every node so we could as easily have called add onto either one of these children nodes, this is how we can build out our tree structure.

So when you first create a tree its going to start off with an empty root property.

Finally, you have to implement your traverse methods, the breadth-first in your case since you mention going from left to right and all you have to do is implement this:

`traverseBF(callback)`

As far as a visual diagram just draw a pyramid of boxes with arrows pointing from the first single box at the top of the pyramid on down representing parent to child nodes and then another set of arrows for each row of boxes pointing towards the right, indicating left to right. You can use a tool like draw.io.